# Can any one change this query to delete

Tags: sql

```
select a.courseid from branch b 
    left outer join course a on a.courseid = b.courseid
where a.courseid is NULL
```

i want to delete that rows which is given by this query

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to delete branch records that do not have a courseid in the course table. If that's right, then:

```
delete b
    from branch b 
        left outer join course a
            on a.courseid = b.courseid  
    where a.courseid is NULL
```

Comment: i already use this query but it is not working.but it is not deleting any rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE a 
FROM branch b 
        left outer join course a
            on a.courseid = b.courseid  
where a.courseid is NULL
```

Is this what You want?

Comment: Deleting rows from a is somewhat pointless given the where clause designed to only select rows from b where there isn't a corresponding row from a.

Comment: Right, didn't notice the "is null" in where clause... I'm wondering what result does this SELECT query has... a set of NULLs?

Comment: this query is not working.it is showing no row affected.plz give me another solution

Comment: please change it for oracle.Any help will be apriciated

Comment: hi piotr, please change this query in oracle.